# How to update ng-repeat after updating array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a following controller

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $interval,$mdToast, $document, $mdDialog,$timeout,$mdDialog) {
var stops=[
    {
      stopName:"testinput1",
      noOfStudents:2
    },
    {
      stopName:"testinput2",
      noOfStudents:2
    },
    {
      stopName:"testinput3",
      noOfStudents:4
    }
]; 

$scope.list=stops;


$scope.addStop=function(name,noOfstudent){
    stops.push({
      stopName:name,
      noODstudent:noOfstudent      
      })
    $scope.list=stops;
}
});
```

in my view I have following code,

```
 <md-list id="stopList">
      <md-list-item  class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in list" style="background:rgb(233, 233, 233);margin:10px;padding-left: 10px;position: relative;min-height: 60px;">
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
          <h3>{{item.stopName}}</h3>
          <h4>{{item.noOfStudents}}</h4>
        </div>
          <div ng-show="deleteIcon" ng-click="showConfirm($event);" class='delete_icon'></div>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
```

The issue I am facing is when I add a stop, the ng-repeat list does not get updated. I want the view to be updated as I add a stop. I am taking the user input from angular material dialog.

Comment: are you sure it's $scope..list=stops;?

Comment: I know this is not an answer. But two dots at `$scope..list=stops;` is wrong I guess. May be a problem with your copying over the code into the editor here.

Answer (score 1):

Data will be updated automatically in view after you update it in controller. What problem (may be ) you are facing is typo in addStop function.

You have used two dots when updating list. >> `$scope..list=stops;`

Comment: Try putting data in $scope.stops = { list : stops};  and iterate accordingly.
 As sometimes using scope object conflicts with rootScope. so...

Comment: Problem may be at some other place as you can see in the answer of @maddog, he has it working.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to push to `stop`

Just direct push to `$scope.list`

When stop assigned in the list it'll assign reference if one is updated another will also

```
$scope.list=stops;
```

Like this

```
$scope.list.push({
    stopName: name,
    noODstudent: noOfstudent
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.addStop = function (name, noOfstudent) {
    stops.push({
        stopName: name,
        noODstudent: noOfstudent
    });

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.list = [];
        $scope.list = stops;
    }, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HlzxQ9sqbMbxDiraT22z?p=preview
Seems to be working for me

```
var name = 'l'
var noOfStudents = 5

$scope.addStop=function(){
stops.push({
  stopName:name,
  noOfStudents:noOfStudents      
  })
$scope.list=stops;
}
```

i have used static data but there should not be any problem

Comment: Yeah thanks it is working but when I call addStop() from dialog then it does not work... actually I am using dialog for inputs

Comment: can you create a plnkr for it? there might something else going wrong